# Как рассчитать количество полных лет?

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой что я не так делаю!!! Нужно рассчитать количество полных лет. Где-то я допускаю ошибку.

```js
var mydata = "2.1.1983";

function declOfNum(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return number + " " + titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}

function birthDateToAge(b) {
  var n = new Date(),
    b = new Date(b),
    age = n.getFullYear() - b.getFullYear();
  return n.setFullYear(1970) < b.setFullYear(1970) ? age - 1 : age;
}
document.write(declOfNum(birthDateToAge(mydata), ['год', 'года', 'лет']));
```

Comment: Объясните словами, что делает этот код.

Comment: @Рассчитать нужно количество полных лет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что "2.1.1983" не может быть конвертировано в объект Date, потому из `b = new Date(b)` выходит `NaN`.

Нужно или записать дату другим форматом или по-другому переводить этот формат в объект Date (с ипользованием шаблона нужно формата).

Вот пример с использованием даты в формате  ISO:

```js
var mydata = "1983-01-02"; // ISO 

function declOfNum(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return number + " " + titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}

function birthDateToAge(b) {
  var n = new Date(),
    b = new Date(b),
    age = n.getFullYear() - b.getFullYear();
  return n.setFullYear(1970) < b.setFullYear(1970) ? age - 1 : age;
}
document.write(declOfNum(birthDateToAge(mydata), ['год', 'года', 'лет']));
```

Answer (score 0):

вычитаю 1 от разницы между годами, добавляю 1 если день рождения "в этом году уже был"
d это Date(), например new Date(2000, 2, 4) - 4 марта 2000

```
  function diff(d) {
  const now = new Date()
  const addOne = now.getMonth() - d.getMonth() >= 0 && now.getDate() - d.getDate() >=0
  const diff = now.getFullYear() - d.getFullYear()
  return diff - 1 + (addOne ? 1 : 0)
}
```

Comment: `now.getMonth() - d.getMonth() >= 0 && now.getDate() - d.getDate() >=0` - что здесь проверяется?